# Matlab isbusDay function error

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to execute a programme matlab on 64-bit versions of Windows. The version Origin of programe is:

```
Matlab R2014b
```

and the version of Matlab that i'm runnig the programme on it is:

```
7.10.0.499 (R2010a)
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
Undefined function or method 'isbusday' for input arguments of type 'char'.
```

My function is:

```
function [isHoliday]=detectJourFerie(num_jour,year)

j1=strcat('01 jan ',year);
j2=strcat('01 may ',year);
j3=strcat('08 may ',year);
j4=strcat('14 jul ',year);
j5=strcat('15 aug ',year);
j6=strcat('01 nov ',year);
j7=strcat('11 nov ',year);
j8=strcat('25 dec ',year);

holidays=[j1;j2;j3;j4;j5;j6;j7;j8];
t = datenum(strcat('01-jan-',year));
currentDay=datestr(addtodate(t, num_jour-1, 'day'));
isHoliday= isbusday(currentDay,holidays);

end
```

Now i dont know where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `isbusday` seems not to exist in your installation. Probably you are missing the [needed Financial Toolbox](http://de.mathworks.com/help/finance/isbusday.html)?

---

BTW, I think your logic is wrong: better use `isHoliday= ~isbusday(currentDay,holidays);`.

And, creating your dates is not optimal as well; I'd do instead the following:

```
function [isHoliday]=detectJourFerie(num_jour,year)

j1=datenum([year 1 1]);
j2=datenum([year 5 1]);
j3=datenum([year 5 8]);
j4=datenum([year 7 14]);
j5=datenum([year 8 15]);
j6=datenum([year 11 1]);
j7=datenum([year 11 11]);
j8=datenum([year 12 25]);

myholidays=[j1;j2;j3;j4;j5;j6;j7;j8];
% or just:
myholidays=cellfun(@(d)datenum([year d]), {[1 1]; [5 1]; [5 8]; [7 14]; [8 15]; [11 1]; [11 11]; [12 25]});

t = datenum([year 1 1]);
currentDay=addtodate(t, num_jour-1, 'day');
isHoliday=~isbusday(currentDay,myholidays);

end
```

because in the long run, a `datevec` (`[2015 1 1]`) is easier to handle with while still being readable and also cleaner than a `datestr`. Internally, a `datenum` seems to be the cleanest.

Comment: Thank you for your good suggestion, i added  financial toolbox, but i have always the problem with **datenum**

Comment: @Vampir Which problem is this?

Comment: In fact my error compilator is : `Could not find the 64-bit compiler.  This may indicate that the  
         "X64 Compilers and Tools" or the Microsoft Windows Software  
         Development Kit (SDK) is not installed.  To build 64-bit MEX-files  
         Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition requires that these two  packages are installed properly `.

Comment: @Vampir Are they installed? However, I don't see why they should be needed here at the first place...

Comment: In your original question, i supposed you used a string variable `year`, since you used `strcat`, but then `datenum` in @glglgl's answer gives error. For datenum, you need numeric variable `year`. If you use `strcat`, you lost space, just use `j1=['01 jan ',year];`. And finally, you should not name the variable `year`, since `year` is a Matlab's built-in function.

Comment: @scmg You are right - it didn't even come to my mind that someone would put a year not in a numeric, but in a string context.